# How I remove controllers name from the route (URL)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

**How I remove controllers name from the route (URL)?**

```
Example :

Existing Url: https://localhost:3000/home/contact_us

I want this URL https://localhost:3000/contact_us
```

so how can I do that?

> Route.rb
>
> get "home/contact_us", to: "home#contact_us", as: :contact_us

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

`get "contact_us", to: "home#contact_us", as: :contact_us`

Answer (score 0):

`get "contact_us", to: "home#contact_us"`

```
as: :contact_us # not required
```